# Java Web Start hangs on some classess

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have made a Java Web Start project with only one `.jar` file. This file is fired by JNLP fire, and it's all right, the app starts, but it hangs when the application tries to do something with classess like `SOAPConnectionFactory` or other.

Why do I know? Because I've made some logging.

What can be the cause? The application is self signed and works perfectly in debug mode.

Comment: The log says?  JNLP imposes some restrictions which you may have hit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide the error message and a [mcve]?

Comment: Program goes to line: SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); and then I get the Exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPConnectionFactory, I don't think that I should add more explanation ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you retry running under Java 8? This seems to be part of the deprecated JEE classes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.ws-summary.html

I had issues with JAXB via JWS under Java 9 and 10, which is deprecated as well.

My attempts to adjust the module loading via JNLP options failed, as did attempts to add JAXB as external jar.

This could be due to errors on my part or due to the semi-removed state of JAXB in Java 9 and 10.

I decided to switch to Jackson and managed to circumvent my JAXB issues. Such an approach might be an option for you.